# How can parse Adobe flash site

Tags: parsing, flash, web-scraping, adobe

I need to parse an Adobe Flash site like this: http://www.ford.ru/SBE/SparePartsLocator/p=1204913942491.
How can I do that?

Comment: Parse it for what info exactly? Also what programming language are you using for this?

Comment: Yes, only for info. It doesn't matter which programming language use for, but i prefer python.

Comment: If you want to extract data from html you can use python's `urllib` to get the url and `bs4` to parse the response.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt work for sites, which are based on adobe flash.